# How to use Euler discretization for this interest rate model?

Tags: interest-rates, stochastic-processes, euler

How can I perform Euler discretization on this model where $\delta t=1$ and $\delta x_t = x_t-x_{t-1}$

[image]

Comment: Hi Qurban Abbasov, welcome to Quant.SE! I've cleaned up the question, can you please verify? Also what is $\gamma$ in (4)?

Comment: Hi Bob Jansen, yes it is correct.thank you. $\gamma$ is just a parameter which is different from 0

Comment: I think he meant whether it was to denote a given $x_t$ or is it used to mean *$x_t$ raised to the power $\gamma$*

Comment: @QurbanAbbasov: Can you please put more input to your question so that people can understand your intention or difficulty.

Answer (score 2):

I would proceed as follows:
\begin{align*}
x_t &= x_{t-\delta t} + \alpha (\beta - x_{t-\delta t}) \delta t + \sigma x_{t-\delta t}^\gamma (w_t - w_{t-\delta t}),\\
x_t &= \max (x_t, \ 0),
\end{align*}
where $w_t - w_{t-\delta t}$ is a normal random variable with mean $0$ and variance $\delta t$, which can be obtained by an independent draw for each time step.

Comment: Gordon, do you have to scale the diffusion term by sqrt(t)?

Comment: @StudentT: I purposely wrote my diffusion term as $w_t-w_{t-\delta t}$ to shorten the explanation. Yes, you can write it as $\xi \sqrt{\delta t}$, where $\xi$ is a standard normal random variable, which is an independent draw at each time step.

Comment: @Gordon Thanks. It was my mistake. I misunderstood the term in the diffusion term was a standard normal. It was my fault. Thanks for the feedback.